# Which is the character for new line when defining a register in vimrc?

Tags: vim

I am trying to do:

`:let @a = 'hello \n world'`

or with `\r`. And then get the output in the file using `"ap`. But I am not getting a new line...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Single quotes are used to define literal strings, in which escape sequences are uninterpreted. If you want the `\n` to be interpreted, use double quotes.

See also: documentation for [single-quoted strings](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#literal-string) and [double-quoted strings](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#expr-string).

Answer (score 1):

Replace single quotes with double quotes.

```
:let @a = "hello \n world"
```